# git fork, but only the latest commit

Tags: git

I am trying to do a fork of a repository, but only the latest commit.
Although the remote says *Unknown commit*

Here's what I'm trying: `git clone -v --bare --depth 1 --single-branch --shallow-submodules https://githost1/repo`

That works, and I only see one commit.

Then I `git push --mirror --porcelain --no-verify https://githost2/repo` and I get `remote: Unknown commit f401f2a20cdbe71f93f66f45400e417e38f58f15`

Any clues?